# Finding power stored/given by each element in a circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

[image]

I will start with my attempt.

I recall my professor saying that $i_1 = 0$ due to the fact that current cannot flow through an open circuit. That makes the current-dependent-voltage-source on the right circuit generate no voltage at all.

Looking at the left circuit, I think that no current will flow through $R_2$ because it will always choose the path of least resistance (through the short circuit); atleast that's what I recall from Sadiku's book. So, I could change the left circuit consisting with only $R_{eq} = R_1$.

On the right circuit, because the current-dependent-voltage-source does not generate any voltage, based on the equation $R = V/I$ I think that the resistance on it should be zero. Hence, I can make the right circuit equivalent to $R_{eq} = \frac{R_3 \cdot R_4}{R_3 + R_2}$.

At this point it's just about finding the voltage or the current in each circuit needed  to calculate the power via $P = V \cdot I$.

Is this approach correct? These are the things that I'm not quite sure of (not explained in the textbook that I use, atleast that I've read yet):

1. Is $i_1$ = 0?
2. Does current flow through $R_2$?
3. Does the CDVS on the right circuit have zero voltage, thus having $P = 0$, and a resistance of zero so I could make $R_{eq}$ as the parallel of $R_3$ and $R_4$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, for the most part.

1. Consider the leftmost circuit. Since, as you said, $R_2$ is short-circuited, we can redraw the leftmost circuit:

[image]

Thus, applying Kirchhoff's Current Law on the blue node yields $i_1=0$.

2. No current flows through $R_2$, since it is short circuited.
3. The voltage across the CCVS is indeed $2i_1=2\cdot0=0V$, so yes, you can replace it with a short circuit, and that would make $R_3$ and $R_4$ be in parallel with each other.

Comment: I see, Kirchoff's Law on the blue node really cleared things up for me. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! When I was a first year student, this approach is what made me wrap my head around why currents such as $i_1$ are equal to $0$.